# RecyclerView: Force items to draw on screen when overlapping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that has circular icon items that overlap with the one after it. I accomplish this with a decoration that takes a negative number and uses it as the 'outRect.right' value and give it a certain elevation. This gives me the desired layered or overlapping effect.

The issue is that the RecyclerView doesn't know when to properly start drawing items as I scroll through the list. Instead of drawing the items as they come on screen, they start drawing once the previous item fully comes into view.

This is a problem since the items are overlapping, a good portion of the items just instantly appear on the screen partially covered by the previous item. Whatever portion of the item that was overlapped should be drawing b/c it's on screen. Instead it waits for the item on top of it to be fully on screen first.

The items should begin drawing once they are on screen. Not wait until the previous item is completely on screen.

My Activity XML

```java
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Initializing the RecyclerView

```java
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
        navigationRecylerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        navigationRecylerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorator(-circleOverlap));
        navigationRecylerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

My Decoration

```java
public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private final int mSpace;

        public ItemDecorator(int space) {
            this.mSpace = space;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            if(position == 0)
                outRect.right = mSpace/3;
            else
                outRect.right = mSpace;
        }
    }
```

And the Navigation Item

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_tab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_tab"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/navigation_item_tab"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/navigation_item_tab"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/navigation_item_tab"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/primary_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Without code examples it's going to be nearly impossible to diagnose the problem

Comment: I'm not too sure what code to put. It's fairly boiler plate. I can paste my code that I use for the recyclerview, the items, and the decoration. But I feel like it's all so standard none of it really impacts the issue of forcing the views to draw when they're on screen instead of when the previous view is completely on screen

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you find a solution? because I'm facing the same issue.